# Expected a value of type 'ImageProvider<Object>', but got one of type 'Image'

Tags: flutter, web

I'm building a web app with flutter and I want an option to change the profile picture. To pick image from gallery I use the `image_picker_web 2.1.1` package.

```
class ImagePickerService {
  late Image? img = Image.asset('whatever'); //has to be initialised
  Future<void> pickImage() async {
    img = await ImagePickerWeb.getImageAsWidget();
  }
}
```

I didn't set the type of `pickImage()` to Future<Image?> because then I'd have to convert from Future. This asset('whatever'), although not very elegant, doesn't cause any problems because before `_fileLoaded` is set to true while picking an image, I display username's initial letter as avatar. Without it I was getting an error of no initialisation.

Relevant snippets from settings page class:

```
  late Image? avatar;
  bool _fileLoaded = false;
  final ImagePickerService _ips = ImagePickerService();


  Center(
            child: displayAvatar(),
          ),
  TextButton.icon(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                _ips.pickImage();
                avatar = _ips.img;
                _fileLoaded = true;
              });
            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.edit),
            label: const Text('Change avatar'),
          ),


  Widget displayAvatar() {
    if (_fileLoaded) {
      return CircleAvatar(
          backgroundImage: avatar as ImageProvider, radius: 50.0);
    } else...
```

I searched for similar problems, but didn't find any answer except for adding `as ImageProvider`, which in my case removes the error from IDE and lets me run the project, but the error appears later on the red screen when I press the button to change avatar, even though the type should be correct. Please, do you know any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting the solution, in case someone has the same problem.
I switched back to the image_picker package, it supports web too, you just have to use it a bit differently:

```
class ImagePickerService {
  final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
  Uint8List picked = Uint8List(8);
  Future<void> pickImage() async {
    XFile? image = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (image != null) picked = await image.readAsBytes();
  }
}

ClipOval(
        child: Image.memory(
          avatar,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          width: 100.0,
          height: 100.0,
        ),
      )
```

`avatar` is assigned to `_ips.picked`, so it's of Uint8List type.

Answer (score 0):

ImageProvider is an abstract class. Classes that implement ImageProvider are AssetImage(""), NetworkImage("URL"), FileImage() etc. I believe FileImage should be well suited for your case.